# How to put an animation on a thread in kivy

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I am making a loading screen for an app and have a little problem with running an animation and an algorithm (which takes a long time to run) at the same time. However when I run that chunk of code, I get the error  AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute  '**getattr**' when i try call 'self.ids.loading_anim'. Can anybody reccomend a better way to multithread an animation in kivy? Bear in mind that when I multithread the other algorithm, it takes too long to run.

Python code:

```
def animate_image(self):
    anim = Animation()  
    anim.start(self.ids.loading_anim)

class LoadingWindow(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        t = Thread(target=animate_image, args=(self))
        t.deamon = True 
        t.start()

        for x in range(5):
            print(x)        # this is just a test algorithm which takes 5 seconds to run
            time.sleep(1)   # in the real file there is another algorithm which takes time to run
```

Kivy Code

```
<LoadingWindow>
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: animation
            source: 'loading.gif'
            size_hint_x:0.6
            size_hint_y:0.6
            pos_hint: {'x':0.19, 'y':0.2}
            allow_stretch: True
            anim_delay: 0
            anim_reset: True
        Label:
            text: 'Searching the internet for recipes....'
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.3}
            font_size: 28
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. I'm halfway sure that this error is not specific to multithreading or kivy, which is what this will determine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I think the function animate_image() can be placed inside the class ?

and the error you get is because `self.ids` don't have a key called `loading_anim` , I think it should be `animation` by referencing to the .kv file ?

on the other hand , I think you can also thread the algorithm as well ?

I also added the class `MyApp` with Inherit to the kivy.app.App and put the LoadingWindow class to kivy ScreenManager. See if this is what you want.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

import kivy
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

kivy.lang.Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 2.0.0

<LoadingWindow>

    FloatLayout:
    
        Image:
            id: animation
            source: 'loading.gif'
            size_hint_x:0.6
            size_hint_y:0.6
            pos_hint: {'x':0.19, 'y':0.2}
            allow_stretch: True
            anim_delay: 0
            anim_reset: True
            
        Label:
            text: 'Searching the internet for recipes....'
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.3}
            font_size: 28

""")


class LoadingWindow(Screen):
    
    def animate_image(self):  # can you put the animate_image() function to here ?
        anim = Animation()
        # anim.start(self.ids.loading_anim)  # I think it should be animation ref to the .kv file ?
        anim.start(self.ids.animation)
        
    
    def your_algorithm(self):
        
        for x in range(5):
            print(x)        # this is just a test algorithm which takes 5 seconds to run
            time.sleep(1)   # in the real file there is another algorithm which takes time to run
            
            
    def on_enter(self):
        t = Thread(target = self.animate_image)
        t.deamon = True
        t.start()
        
        # instead of threading the animation , I think you can also thread the algorithm ?
        algorithm = Thread(target = self.your_algorithm)
        algorithm.start()


class MyApp(App):
    screen_manager = ScreenManager()
    
    def build(self):
        # add screen to screen manager
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(LoadingWindow(name = "LoadingWindow"))
        
        return self.screen_manager


MyApp().run()
```

any other suggestions / recommendations / better method / etc. is welcome  : )

( sry for bad English )

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problems with `on_pre_enter` & `on_enter`

from my knowledge the function `on_pre_enter` and `on_enter` is called before the screen ids loaded but i found a way you can use

try this code:

```py
from kivy.clock import Clock

def animate_image(self):
    anim = Animation()  
    anim.start(self.ids.loading_anim)

class LoadingWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init_completed)
    def init_completed(self, dt):
        t = Thread(target=animate_image, args=(self))
        t.deamon = True 
        t.start()

        for x in range(5):
            print(x)        # this is just a test algorithm which takes 5 seconds to run
            time.sleep(1)   # in the real file there is another algorithm which takes time to run
```

as i said in the `Screen` `on_pre_enter` and `on_enter` is called before ids loaded but with this way the ids are loaded then your function init_completed is called

worked for me.